# How to run easy.py of libsvm in window?

Tags: windows, svm, libsvm

I am new to the libsvm and sorry for some silly questions.
I am trying to run easy.py but have problems to do so.  I have

1. downloaded the libsvm-3.1 package and extract it into *C:\User\Cassie\libsvm*
2. Install Python and it created a folder at *C:/Python27*
3. Download *gp443win32.zip* and extract it to a folder gnuplot at Download folder. Make a copy of *gnuplot.exe* and paste it to *C:\User\Cassie\libsvm3-1\libsvm3-1\tools*
4. invoke cmd at Window 7 and typed "easy.py myfile.txt". But an error message showed

"Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\User\Cassie\libsvm-3.1\libsvm-3.1\tools\easy.py", line 31, in  
    assert os.path.exists(gnuplot_exe),"gnuplot executable not found"
AssertionError: gnuplot executable not found"

Questions:

1. Did I install the wrong gnuplot package?
2. Did I move the wrong application ? *gnuplot.exe*
3. Did I need to configure some path or envinroment to make the cmd find *gnuplot.exe* ?
4. Did I type the wrong command to make *easy.py* run ?
5. Do I have to label the training file first ?

There are much information at libsvm and I was really confused. Any experience with this issue is welcome. Thank you all very much,

Answer (score 12):

It looks like a "path problem".
So open easy.py in text editor and go the line 25 which will look something like "gnuplot_exe = r"c:\tmp\Desktop\gnuplot\bin\pgnuplot.exe".

so you need to put the exact path of gnuplot stored , for example for me it was  "gnuplot_exe = r"c:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\gnuplot\binary\pgnuplot.exe".

I Hope this will help you!!!

Comment: Thank you very much. The easy.py seems abling to run now although my gnuplot can not plot anything. I will try to fix it.:)

Comment: Hi @Cassie, Now i am having some problem in running easy.py. This is what I'am getting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990736/how-to-modify-easy-py-in-libsvm-3-18-to-solve-error-trackback-most-recent-call. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check your path of gnuplot.exe, check every character;
2. Please install other version of gnuplot, maybe the version of gnuplot is incompatible whih the current version of libSVM;
3. In my computer, LibSVM 3.2.1 gnuplot 5.0.1 python 2.7. It is OK!