# How to modify easy.py in libsvm-3.18 to solve error "Trackback <most recent call last>: File "easy.py", line 6----

Tags: libsvm

While using easy.py script it generates error as shown in figure:

[image]

Path for gnuplot is set well. There is no problem in using grid.py

Some people suggested (http://www.cnblogs.com/tekson/archive/2009/05/25/1489222.html) to change following line in easy.py:

cmd = '{0} -svmtrain "{1}" -gnuplot "{2}" "{3}"'.format(grid_py, svmtrain_exe, gnuplot_exe, scaled_file)

But no idea how to modify above code line to resolve the problem.

If anyone have got same problem and solved this, please let me know. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose to remove lines 56-63 and replace line 65 with the above.

Comment: Thanks for reply @pacholik, however that do not seems to work because we need c, g, rate values which are generated from lines 56-63.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. I think it will be helpful for those who are facing same problem.

Thanks to: http://huangbo929.blog.edu.cn/home.php?mod=space&uid=294073&do=blog&id=70541

**Solution:**

Replace Line

**"cmd = '{0} -svmtrain "{1}" -gnuplot "{2}" "{3}"'.format(grid_py, svmtrain_exe, gnuplot_exe, scaled_file)"**

With

**cmd = 'python {0} -svmtrain "{1}" -gnuplot "{2}" "{3}"'.format(grid_py, svmtrain_exe, gnuplot_exe, scaled_file)**